# Eulerian Circuit-Cycle Decompositions

Tags: graph-theory, eulerian-path

For some background information, Eulerian here refers to starting and ending on the same vertex (i.e. being closed).

Also, the corollary below uses Theorem 3.4 which states a graph is Eulerian iff each edge lies on an odd number of cycles.

> $\textbf{Question:}$ What is the reason that $s(G)\equiv \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^rs_i$ holds true at the  very bottom of the proof below?

[image]

This corollary is found on page 68 [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=tqOfDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA64&lpg=PA64&dq=There%20are%20many%20games%20and%20puzzles%20which%20can%20be%20analysed%20by%20graph%20theoretic%20concepts.%20In%20fact,%20the%20two%20early%20discoveries%20which%20led%20to%20the%20existence%20of%20graphs%20arose%20from%20puzzles,%20namely,%20the%20Konigsberg%20Bridge%20Problem%20and%20Hamiltonian%20Game,%20and%20these%20puzzles%20also%20resulted%20in%20the%20special%20types%20of%20graphs,%20now%20called%20Eulerian%20graphs%20and%20Hamiltonian&source=bl&ots=6ZKwxeZTcc&sig=ACfU3U2eZAvOWWS3ppacKSv17TdX7A2LdQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjYiuvh_vboAhVXJ80KHTnwBEYQ6AEwAXoECAwQKQ#v=onepage&q=There%20are%20many%20games%20and%20puzzles%20which%20can%20be%20analysed%20by%20graph%20theoretic%20concepts.%20In%20fact%2C%20the%20two%20early%20discoveries%20which%20led%20to%20the%20existence%20of%20graphs%20arose%20from%20puzzles%2C%20namely%2C%20the%20Konigsberg%20Bridge%20Problem%20and%20Hamiltonian%20Game%2C%20and%20these%20puzzles%20also%20resulted%20in%20the%20special%20types%20of%20graphs%2C%20now%20called%20Eulerian%20graphs%20and%20Hamiltonian&f=false).

Note I do understand the following in the proof:

> $\text{ Set of All Cycle Decompositions of G}=\{\text{Every Cycle Decomposition of } G_i \cup C_i\}_{i=1, 2, ..., r}$
>
> and that $s_i=|\text{Every Cycle Decomposition of } G_i \cup C_i |$ in consideration as to what is inside the set above.
>
> > At a glance, $s(G)=\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^r s_i$ holds true by simply adding up each cycle decomposition at a time to get the total number.
> >
> > However, wouldn't there be a chance that a cycle decomposition of $G_i$ $\cup C_i$ might be equal to a cycle decomposition of $G_j\cup C_j$ where $i\neq j$ which seems like a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that concerns you would arise only if $C_i$ appeared in a cycle decomposition of $G_j$ for some $j\ne i$. This cannot happen, however, because $C_i$ and $C_j$ both contain the edge $e$ chosen at the start of the proof: no cycle in a cycle decomposition of $C_j$ can contain $e$, since it belongs to $C_j$, and therefore no cycle in a cycle decomposition of $G_j$ can be $C_i$, which also contains $e$.

Comment: Ohhhhhhh!!! That is sneaky how you did that! I was not even thinking about the edge e being involved at this point in the proof. Excellent answer! Thank you so much!

Comment: @W.G.: You’re very welcome!